# Cannot connect to secure wifi network

Tags: 8.0, lumia, wifi

On my Nokia Lumia 620, whenever I try to connect to a secure wi-fi network that uses WPA2 Enterprise for security and 802.1x (PEAP using MSCHAPv2) as its authentication method, I get an error message saying "could not reach wifi network" even though I know it's in range and I know the password is correct.

This seems to have been [reported earlier on the Microsoft Answers community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpdevices/cannot-connect-to-secure-wifi-router/bb20377a-317b-4b9d-9966-be6dd039adf2) as well as [news sites](http://www.electronista.com/articles/10/11/09/dell.venue.pro.htc.hd7.hit.with.secure.wi.fi.bug/). That was for Windows Phone 7 though. Does the same bug exist to this day, and if yes, is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @HaLaBi Nope :/

Comment: I think it will be fixed in GDR3, along with TTLS suport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved in the end by two different things, and I'm not sure which one was more critical so I'm mentioning both:

- I got the **GDR3** update
- ..and more importantly, my company deployed a mobile device management (MDM) solution that automatically downloads and installs company certificates which are used for authentication on the WiFi network.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in GDR3 update - make sure you have updated your phone to at least 8.0.10512.142

If your carrier doesn't have the update you can get it the following way:

***EDIT: THIS WILL VOID YOUR WARRANTY***

- ·         Go to http://apps.windowsstore.com and login with
  Microsoft Live ID.
- Tap on OS Preview for Developers ·

  Scroll down and click on Download button, it will take you to
  “Preview for Developers” app screen ·
- Click on install , it    will initiate install on the device remotely
  if not It will send the    mail to the same account, open the link to
  install the app ·
- Install the app and accept terms and    conditions and go check for
  updates again from settings screen. ·
- Boom you will be on    GDR3

J