# Protocol, certificate or setting that prevents Lumia 735 from connecting WiFi

Tags: wifi, nokia-lumia-735

My Lumia 735 is [unable to access my home WiFi network](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12267/11237)<sup>1</sup>. Since I'm able to access the very same network from a number of other devices, including:

- Lumia 535 Dual SIM,
- Lumia 635,
- Luma 640,
- various Android-based devices,
- Apple iPad Mini tablet,
- Lark Ultimate 71 tablet (see edited notice in the end).

Problem certainly lies both in [router configuration](https://superuser.com/q/1023667/156554) as well as in Lumia 735's lack of mentioned protocol, certificate, setting etc.

Any attempt to connect that WiFi networks ends with error (translation from Polish): "*Windows Sockets interface entries are missing in Windows Registry, but are required for network connectivity*".

Since a large number of other Lumias is able to access my network, I'd like to ask if someone can list a number of "things", that are installed on above mentioned Lumias, that are (for any reason) missing in Lumia 735, so I could track down source of this problem?

**Edit:** My current wireless network configuration (as read directly from router):

- SSID broadcast: **no**.
- 802.11 Mode: **802.11b/g Mixed**.
- Channel (ETSI): **Automatic**.
- Encryption: **AES**.
- Network Authentication: **Open System Authentication**.
- Security: **WPA2**.
- Authentication Method: **Pre-Shared Key**.
- Encryption Algorithm: **AES**.
- Group Key Update Interval: **(*unchecked*; 0 seconds)**.

My router configuration was different, when initially asking this question (in particular: *Channels* was set to some fixed value, *Encryption* was set to *AES+TKIP* and *Security* was set to *WPA+WPA2*). I found all this settings weird and changed them to above.

I have another device, Lark Ultimate 7i tablet with Windows 10, on which I was observing exactly the same problems. Changing router configuration from initial to above solved problem for tablet, but Lumia 735 still is unable to access my wireless network.

<sup>1</sup><sub>By "unable to access" I mean, that Lumia is initially correctly detecting my wireless network and it is correctly recognizing it as WPA2, as it is asking me to provide my WPA2 key. Once key (validated three times as correct) is provided, after about 30 seconds Lumia claims, that my network stopped responding. If I intentionally provide an incorrect WPA2 key, then Lumia is able to detect it and display error about wrong WPA key instead. But, once correct WPA key is provided then it again claims, that network stopped responding. Each attempt to reconnect this network (either directly or after phone and/or router restart) ends with the same story happening again, i.e. network is found, security is detected, request for providing WPA key is displayed and when key is provided, device again and again claims, that network stopped responding.</sub>

Comment: Sounds like a fault with your phone, but can you confirm what type of network it is you're trying to connect to, as some older phones do not support 802.11ac

Comment: @RowlandShaw Please, see my updated answer. Type of network is currently set to _802.1b/g Mixed_ and Lumia 735 is still unable to access this network.